# Views - How to suppress ajax errors without leaving a log entry in browser

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a views page that is continually updated using views_autorefresh.  My setup works fine except for the occasional error message:

AJAX Request terminated abnormally

This only happens if the user tries to navigate away from the page during an update.  Is there a way to suppress this message?  Because I know that this message will happen (repeatedly) I do not want for there to be a log entry of it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by the [Prevent JS Alerts](https://drupal.org/project/prevent_js_alerts) module